# What's the role of bromelain in pineapple?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, proteins, food

[Bromelain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromelain) refers to one of two proteases found in pineapple and its relatives. Like other proteases, many believe it has therapeutic uses and it's the subject of a lot of research. But what role does it play in the pineapple itself? Why does pineapple (or papaya, for that matter) generate large quantities of protease when other plants do not?

Answer (score 1):

Antifungal properties? as tested in below article.

López‐García, B., Hernández, M. and Segundo, B.S., 2012. **Bromelain, a cysteine protease from pineapple (Ananas comosus) stem, is an inhibitor of fungal plant pathogens**. *Letters in applied microbiology*, 55(1), pp.62-67. [Available here](https://sfamjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1472-765X.2012.03258.x)

Comment: Please cite scientific papers fully using a formal citation guide. (Google Scholar does all the work for you if you want): see [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C36&q=Bromelain%2C+a+cysteine+protease+from+pineapple+%28Ananas+comosus%29+stem%2C+is+an+inhibitor+of+fungal+plant+pathogens%22&btnG=)

Comment: Citing is absolutely necessary here, so thank you for pointing toward a reputable study (though see my comment above and my edits). However, posts citing other's work need to summarize, quote, or otherwise explain the rationale for including the citation (especially if no further explanation is provided as part of the answer). Answers on SE need to be complete in and of themselves -- as in someone 5 years from now should be able to view your answer and feel like they had the question adequately answered without needing to leave the site. External links and citations can be for further reading

Comment: I thought the name of the paper was a good answer already, didn't want to waste peoples time reading long answers.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Please reread theforestecologist's comment, this is site policy not one person's opinion. Link only answers are frowned upon and decrease the quality of StackExchange. An answer doesn't need to become "long" to include more than just a link.